Cannot install h5py and thus cellprofiler packages
I am trying to get Cellprofiler working again on ARM64 EC2 instances in AWS. This previously worked but on the latest Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, it won't successfully install anymore. I've boiled it down to the (hopefully last) package that needs to be installed: h5py v3.6.0
Unfortunately when running pip install h5py everything goes smoothly but when running pip install cellprofiler it tries to install h5py<4,~=3.6.0 and that's where the following errors come from:
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting git+https://github.com/h5py/h5py.git@3.6.0
  Cloning https://github.com/h5py/h5py.git (to revision 3.6.0) to /tmp/pip-req-build-dhg1ew8t
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/h5py/h5py.git /tmp/pip-req-build-dhg1ew8t
  Running command git checkout -q 3a4b4eeaa6e1ace087962f4db0e4e0b11164d07d
  Resolved https://github.com/h5py/h5py.git to commit 3a4b4eeaa6e1ace087962f4db0e4e0b11164d07d
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from h5py==3.6.0) (1.26.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: h5py
  Building wheel for h5py (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for h5py (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for h5py (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [532 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310
      creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py
      copying h5py/ipy_completer.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py
      copying h5py/version.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py
      copying h5py/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py
      copying h5py/h5py_warnings.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py
      creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/datatype.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/group.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/dataset.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/base.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/filters.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/selections2.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/attrs.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/files.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/selections.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/vds.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/dims.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/_hl
      creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/common.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_dataset.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_h5f.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_dtype.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_h5.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_base.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_file_image.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_datatype.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_h5t.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_dimension_scales.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_h5o.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_errors.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/conftest.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_attrs.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_dataset_swmr.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_h5d_direct_chunk.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_slicing.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_attribute_create.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_completions.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_objects.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_big_endian_file.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_h5pl.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_file2.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_group.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_file.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_dims_dimensionproxy.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_h5p.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_filters.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_attrs_data.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_selections.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_dataset_getitem.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests
      creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests/data_files
      copying h5py/tests/data_files/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests/data_files
      creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests/test_vds
      copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_lowlevel_vds.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests/test_vds
      copying h5py/tests/test_vds/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests/test_vds
      copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_highlevel_vds.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests/test_vds
      copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_virtual_source.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests/test_vds
      copying h5py/tests/data_files/vlen_string_dset.h5 -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests/data_files
      copying h5py/tests/data_files/vlen_string_s390x.h5 -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests/data_files
      copying h5py/tests/data_files/vlen_string_dset_utc.h5 -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/h5py/tests/data_files
      running build_ext
      warning: h5py/defs.pxd:15:0: The 'IF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using runtime conditions or C macros instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310
      ...(shortened it due to a character limit on StackOverflow)
      warning: h5py/defs.pxd:385:0: The 'IF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using runtime conditions or C macros instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310
      warning: h5py/api_types_hdf5.pxd:48:2: The 'IF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using runtime conditions or C macros instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310
      ...(shortened it due to a character limit on StackOverflow)
      warning: h5py/api_types_ext.pxd:52:4: The 'IF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using runtime conditions or C macros instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310
      warning: h5py/_conv.pyx:161:8: The 'IF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using runtime conditions or C macros instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310
      warning: h5py/_conv.pyx:422:8: The 'IF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using runtime conditions or C macros instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310
      warning: h5py/h5r.pxd:17:0: The 'IF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using runtime conditions or C macros instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      # License:  Standard 3-clause BSD; see "license.txt" for full license terms
      #           and contributor agreement.
      
      from .defs cimport *
      
      from ._objects cimport class ObjectID
                             ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/h5t.pxd:13:23: Expected an identifier
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      
      from logging import getLogger
      
      from .h5 import get_config
      from .h5r cimport Reference, RegionReference, hobj_ref_t, hdset_reg_ref_t
      from .h5t cimport H5PY_OBJ, typewrap, py_create, TypeID, H5PY_PYTHON_OPAQUE_TAG
      ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/_conv.pyx:21:0: 'h5py/h5t/H5PY_OBJ.pxd' not found
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      
      from logging import getLogger
      
      from .h5 import get_config
      from .h5r cimport Reference, RegionReference, hobj_ref_t, hdset_reg_ref_t
      from .h5t cimport H5PY_OBJ, typewrap, py_create, TypeID, H5PY_PYTHON_OPAQUE_TAG
      ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/_conv.pyx:21:0: 'h5py/h5t/typewrap.pxd' not found
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      
      from logging import getLogger
      
      from .h5 import get_config
      from .h5r cimport Reference, RegionReference, hobj_ref_t, hdset_reg_ref_t
      from .h5t cimport H5PY_OBJ, typewrap, py_create, TypeID, H5PY_PYTHON_OPAQUE_TAG
      ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/_conv.pyx:21:0: 'h5py/h5t/py_create.pxd' not found
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      
      from logging import getLogger
      
      from .h5 import get_config
      from .h5r cimport Reference, RegionReference, hobj_ref_t, hdset_reg_ref_t
      from .h5t cimport H5PY_OBJ, typewrap, py_create, TypeID, H5PY_PYTHON_OPAQUE_TAG
      ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/_conv.pyx:21:0: 'h5py/h5t/TypeID.pxd' not found
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      
      from logging import getLogger
      
      from .h5 import get_config
      from .h5r cimport Reference, RegionReference, hobj_ref_t, hdset_reg_ref_t
      from .h5t cimport H5PY_OBJ, typewrap, py_create, TypeID, H5PY_PYTHON_OPAQUE_TAG
      ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/_conv.pyx:21:0: 'h5py/h5t/H5PY_PYTHON_OPAQUE_TAG.pxd' not found
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
          void* ptr
      
      cdef int conv_vlen2ndarray(void* ipt,
                                 void* opt,
                                 cnp.dtype elem_dtype,
                                 TypeID intype,
                                 ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/_conv.pyx:687:27: 'TypeID' is not a type identifier
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      
      cdef int conv_vlen2ndarray(void* ipt,
                                 void* opt,
                                 cnp.dtype elem_dtype,
                                 TypeID intype,
                                 TypeID outtype) except -1:
                                 ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/_conv.pyx:688:27: 'TypeID' is not a type identifier
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
          return 0
      
      
      cdef int conv_ndarray2vlen(void* ipt,
                                 void* opt,
                                 TypeID intype,
                                 ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/_conv.pyx:820:27: 'TypeID' is not a type identifier
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      
      
      cdef int conv_ndarray2vlen(void* ipt,
                                 void* opt,
                                 TypeID intype,
                                 TypeID outtype) except -1:
                                 ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/_conv.pyx:821:27: 'TypeID' is not a type identifier
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
          :return: error-code
          """
          cdef:
              int command = cdata[0].command
              size_t src_size, dst_size
              TypeID supertype
              ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/_conv.pyx:629:8: 'TypeID' is not a type identifier
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
          """
          cdef:
              int command = cdata[0].command
              size_t src_size, dst_size
              TypeID supertype
              TypeID outtype
              ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/_conv.pyx:630:8: 'TypeID' is not a type identifier
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
                               void *bkg_i,
                               hid_t dxpl) except -1 with gil:
          cdef:
              int command = cdata[0].command
              size_t src_size, dst_size
              TypeID supertype
              ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/_conv.pyx:752:8: 'TypeID' is not a type identifier
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
                               hid_t dxpl) except -1 with gil:
          cdef:
              int command = cdata[0].command
              size_t src_size, dst_size
              TypeID supertype
              TypeID outtype
              ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/_conv.pyx:753:8: 'TypeID' is not a type identifier
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
          cdef char* ctag = NULL
          try:
              if H5Tget_class(obj) == H5T_OPAQUE:
                  ctag = H5Tget_tag(obj)
                  if ctag != NULL:
                      if strcmp(ctag, H5PY_PYTHON_OPAQUE_TAG) == 0:
                                      ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/_conv.pyx:157:32: 'H5PY_PYTHON_OPAQUE_TAG' is not a constant, variable or function identifier
      warning: h5py/_conv.pyx:157:32: Obtaining 'const char *' from externally modifiable global Python value
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
          elif command == H5T_CONV_FREE:
              pass
      
          elif command == H5T_CONV_CONV:
              # need to pass element dtype to converter
              supertype = typewrap(H5Tget_super(src_id))
                          ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/_conv.pyx:645:20: 'typewrap' is not a constant, variable or function identifier
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      
          elif command == H5T_CONV_CONV:
              # need to pass element dtype to converter
              supertype = typewrap(H5Tget_super(src_id))
              dt = supertype.dtype
              outtype = py_create(dt)
                        ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/_conv.pyx:647:18: 'py_create' is not a constant, variable or function identifier
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
              PyObject *pdata_elem
              char* buf = <char*>buf_i
      
          if command == H5T_CONV_INIT:
              cdata[0].need_bkg = H5T_BKG_NO
              if not H5Tequal(src_id, H5PY_OBJ) or H5Tget_class(dst_id) != H5T_VLEN:
                                      ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/_conv.pyx:761:32: 'H5PY_OBJ' is not a constant, variable or function identifier
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      
          if command == H5T_CONV_INIT:
              cdata[0].need_bkg = H5T_BKG_NO
              if not H5Tequal(src_id, H5PY_OBJ) or H5Tget_class(dst_id) != H5T_VLEN:
                  return -2
              supertype = typewrap(H5Tget_super(dst_id))
                          ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/_conv.pyx:763:20: 'typewrap' is not a constant, variable or function identifier
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
                  return -2
              supertype = typewrap(H5Tget_super(dst_id))
              for i in range(nl):
                  # smells a lot
                  memcpy(&pdata_elem, pdata+i, sizeof(pdata_elem))
                  if supertype != py_create((<cnp.ndarray> pdata_elem).dtype, 1):
                                  ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/_conv.pyx:767:28: 'py_create' is not a constant, variable or function identifier
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
              if nl == 0:
                  return 0
      
              # need to pass element dtype to converter
              pdata_elem = pdata[0]
              supertype = py_create((<cnp.ndarray> pdata_elem).dtype)
                          ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/_conv.pyx:784:20: 'py_create' is not a constant, variable or function identifier
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
                  return 0
      
              # need to pass element dtype to converter
              pdata_elem = pdata[0]
              supertype = py_create((<cnp.ndarray> pdata_elem).dtype)
              outtype = typewrap(H5Tget_super(dst_id))
                        ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/_conv.pyx:785:18: 'typewrap' is not a constant, variable or function identifier
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      
          enum = H5Tenum_create(H5T_STD_I32LE)
      
          vlentype = H5Tvlen_create(H5T_STD_I32LE)
      
          pyobj = H5PY_OBJ
                  ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      h5py/_conv.pyx:894:12: 'H5PY_OBJ' is not a constant, variable or function identifier
      Loading library to get build settings and version: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so
      ********************************************************************************
                             Summary of the h5py configuration
      
      HDF5 include dirs: [
        '/usr/include/hdf5/serial'
      ]
      HDF5 library dirs: [
        '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial'
      ]
           HDF5 Version: (1, 10, 7)
            MPI Enabled: False
       ROS3 VFD Enabled: True
       Rebuild Required: True
      
      ********************************************************************************
      Executing api_gen rebuild of defs
      Executing cythonize()
      [ 1/24] Cythonizing /tmp/pip-req-build-dhg1ew8t/h5py/_conv.pyx
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rmuz9tpt/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 415, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rmuz9tpt/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 397, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rmuz9tpt/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 313, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 104, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rmuz9tpt/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rmuz9tpt/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 184, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rmuz9tpt/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 200, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rmuz9tpt/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rmuz9tpt/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 976, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rmuz9tpt/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rmuz9tpt/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_wheel.py", line 373, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rmuz9tpt/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 316, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rmuz9tpt/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 976, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rmuz9tpt/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rmuz9tpt/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 132, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rmuz9tpt/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 316, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rmuz9tpt/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 976, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rmuz9tpt/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-req-build-dhg1ew8t/setup_build.py", line 170, in run
          self.extensions = cythonize(self._make_extensions(config),
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rmuz9tpt/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1154, in cythonize
          cythonize_one(*args)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rmuz9tpt/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1321, in cythonize_one
          raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
      Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: /tmp/pip-req-build-dhg1ew8t/h5py/_conv.pyx
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
Failed to build h5py
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (h5py)


These errors can be created by running pip3 install "h5py<4,~=3.6.0" or pip install git+https://github.com/h5py/h5py.git@3.6.0, also with the --use-pep517 and/or --no-binary flags. I've tried compiling it with Cython 3.0.10 and 0.29.x versions, looked at many solutions such as running pip install versioned-hdf5 first. This installs the latest h5py without any issues, but Cellprofiler runs into the same issue again when trying to install that specific version.
Any and all help is appreciated!
